# How to bind attributes to a Qt custom form?

Tags: qgis, qt

I have followed this helpful [post](http://woostuff.wordpress.com/2012/03/30/custom-qgis-feature-forms-value-binding/) on creating a custom form. I have named the Qt objects the same as the fields in my attribute table. I have also set the edit widget properties to text edit for the line edit widget etc.

The form pops up when I click on a feature, but none of the data appears in the custom form.

Can anyone suggest what might be the problem?

Comment: Not without seeing some code, specifically yours. Too many things can go wrong to try to guess. Can you edit your question with a sample of your code please.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you only provided a .ui file but did not configure the widgets.

Go to Layer Properties > Fields and change (and configure) the widget type according to your needs.

E.g. Range for a Spin Box